# Is there a way to determine if there is an attachment in a calculated column?

Tags: 2007, calculated-column, attachments

I'd like to have a column display "Yes" if there is an attachment to the sharepoint list item, or "No" if there isn't one.  Default would be no, but then if they edit the item to add an attachment, I would like it to calculate to yes.

Is there a way to do this in SP 2007?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to do this without an event receiver or other managed code.  A Calculated Column cannot retrieve the Attachments flag.